# D3 sort descending for multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: d3.js

```
data = [[1062, 732, 1327754], [12335, 7693, 109313934], [290, 450, 1768064]];
```

how can I sort by the third value of each array object in my data resulting in the descending sort value of

```
[[12335, 7693, 109313934], [290, 450, 1768064], [1062, 732, 1327754]]
```

I am trying to use the d3 method:
`data.sort(d3.descending);`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to pass `data.sort` a comparison function that will access the third element in each array:

```
data.sort(function(a, b){ return d3.descending(a[2], b[2]); })
```

Here because `data` is a multi-dimensional array, both `a` and `b` will be arrays as well. Then

```
d3.descending(a[2], b[2])
```

performs the comparison of the third element in each array such that the results are returned in descending order.

Comment: Since you're using numbers, it might make more sense to just use `function(a, b) { return b[2] - a[2]; }` rather than the function returned by `d3.descending`, although using d3 is a perfectly fine and arguably more readable solution.

Comment: Good point @Wex. I used `d3.descending` because the OP had explicitly asked for it, and because it is arguably more legible :)

Answer (score 2):

and, if you want to add in a secondary sort so that if the third column values are equal you then sort on the second column:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a[2]===b[2]) {
    return d3.descending(a[1], b[1]);
  }
  return d3.descending(a[2], b[2]);
};
```